# Why is this AND gate neural network not moving towards optimal weights?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have simple neural network of two inputs and one output with no hidden layers. i.e,

```
[input1][weight1 weight2] = z [input2]
output = sigmoid(z)
```

The weights don't seem move to an optimal value. I've checked the gradient to the best of my knowledge and I can see the weights go up or down depending on the derivative of cost function, but network doesn't move towards optimal values.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import random as r
import sys

def sigmoid(ip, derivate=False):
    if derivate:
        return ip*(1-ip)
    return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-1*ip))

class NeuralNet:
    global sigmoid 

    def __init__(self):
        self.inputLayers = 2
        self.outputLayer = 1

    def setup(self):
        self.i = np.array([r.random(), r.random()], dtype=float).reshape(2,)
        self.w = np.array([r.random(), r.random()], dtype=float).reshape(2,)

    def forward_propogate(self):
        self.z = self.w*self.i
        self.o = sigmoid(sum(self.z))

    def optimize_cost(self, desired):
        i=0
        current_cost = pow(desired - self.o, 2)
        for weight in self.w:
            dpdw = -1 * (desired-self.o) * (sigmoid(self.o, derivate=True)) * self.i[i]
            print(dpdw)
            self.w[i] = self.w[i] + 500*dpdw
            i+=1
        self.forward_propogate()

    def train(self, ip, op):
        self.i = np.array(ip).reshape(2,)
        self.forward_propogate()
        print("before:{}".format(self.o))
        self.optimize_cost(op[0])
        # print(self.i,self.w)
n = NeuralNet()
n.setup()
# while sys.stdin.read(1):
while True:
    a = r.random()
    b = r.random()
    if a>0.5 and b>0.5:
        c = 0.9
    else:
        c = 0.1
    print(c)
    n.train([a,b],[c])
    print(n.i, n.w)
    print("after: {}".format(n.o))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. All I needed was a BIAS. Without a BIAS, the sigmoid cannot deviate from 0.

Here's a sigmoid with bias of 2. Now sigmoid(0) = closer to 0.1

[image]

After including a BIAS node in the network, I was able to get the results.

> **Success rate:** 99.00000042272556% Network trained, took: 2365601 trials
> **Network weights:**[14.0435016  14.04351048]
> **Bias:** 21.861074330808844

---

> Enter INPUT:
> 0 
> 1
> Network output:0.00040243926180320134
>
> Enter INPUT: 
> 1
>  1
> Network output:0.9980264340845117

Answer (score 1):

i have read this https://towardsdatascience.com/emulating-logical-gates-with-a-neural-network-75c229ec4cc9 and there is also said that deeper (with (multiple) hidden layers) networks are required to achieve good training results, the reasons mentioned are :

> **Training and Learning**
>
> **Now we have shown that this neural network is possible, now the
>   remaining question is, it is possible to train. Can we expect that if
>   we simply fed in the data drawn from the graph above after defining
>   the layers, number of neurons and activation functions correctly, the
>   network will train in this way?**
>
> **No, not always, and not even often. The problem, like with many neural
>   networks is one of optimization. In training this network it will
>   often get stuck in a local minimum even though a near-perfect solution
>   exists. This is where your optimization algorithm may play a large
>   role, and this is something which Tensorflow Playground doesn’t allow
>   you to change and may be the subject of a future post.**
>
> [...]
>
> **After you have built this network by manually inputting the weights,
>   why not try to train the weights of this this network from scratch
>   instead of constructing it in manually. I have managed to do this
>   after many trials, but I believe it is quite sensitive to the seeding
>   and often ends up in local minimums. If you find a reliable way to
>   train this network using these features and this network structure
>   please reach out in the comments.**
>
> Try to build this network using the only this number of neurons and
>   layers. In this article I have shown that it is possible to do it with
>   this many neurons only. If you introduce any more nodes then you will
>   certainly have some redundant neurons. **Although, with more
>   neurons/layers, I have had better luck in training a good model more
>   consistently.**

Possibly the problem is related to the *multiplication problem* of neural nets. Flat (or non-deep / without hidden layers) neural nets are not able to perform a simple multiplication cf **https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217703/can-deep-neural-network-approximate-multiplication-function-without-normalizatio**

*UPDATE (comment)*

To be honest i am not sure about the MSE error function because it is not good in classification problems, cf https://towardsdatascience.com/why-using-mean-squared-error-mse-cost-function-for-binary-classification-is-a-bad-idea-933089e90df7 and **https://medium.com/autonomous-agents/how-to-teach-logic-to-your-neuralnetworks-116215c71a49** (uses *negative log likelihood* error function that is also known as *multiclass cross-entropy*) and also https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/ :

> Mean Squared Error Loss
>
> **The Mean Squared Error, or MSE, loss is the default loss to use for regression [not classification] problems.**

*source : https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/*

Training two labels or classes (`True`, `False`) is a classification problem, not a regression problem.

however i think the *main systematical problem* is that the network is not deep enough. As said in the article https://towardsdatascience.com/emulating-logical-gates-with-a-neural-network-75c229ec4cc9 you can seed combinations of initial weights to avoid local minima but this also does not solve the basic problems (network not deep enough, wrong error function (MSE)).

In https://towardsdatascience.com/lets-code-a-neural-network-in-plain-numpy-ae7e74410795 is a numpy implementation of a neural network for classification that includes an implementation of *binary cross-entropy* error function, maybe compare this to your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read. Reckon the code & gradient calculation looks alright? I've been spending too much time suspecting that.

Comment: Figured it out. Answered my own question.